# @ in the beginning of the String in C

Tags: c, string, visual-studio-code

UPDATE:
The code itself was fine, I just installed an Extension called "Code Runner" and it solved the problem.

I'm using VS code to write a HelloWorld in C, but when I run it, there is extra @ character in the beginning of each line. Where does this "@" character is coming from and how can I only print the String?
This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
printf("Hello\nWorld");
return 0;
}
```

This is what I get in DEBUG CONSOLE

```
@"Hello\r\n"
@"World"
```

Comment: And what happens when you run the program  on it's own, i.e. so that the output is displayed in your terminal rather than in the debug console?

Comment: Exactly like that? With escaped character literals, an added newline, and the `@`? Odd...

Comment: Probably need to detail your VS Code config.

Comment: This is one of the rare cases where a screenshot needed to prove this.

Comment: Oddly, that looks like what Microsoft calls a [verbatim string literal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim), but that's a C# thing.  I've never seen it used to indicate literal console output.

Comment: The debug console isn't showing normal terminal output, since it's showing the quotes and escape sequences.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with your C++ program. It's your Visual Studio code's configuration (or something close to it) which turns program's output to a sequence of C#-like string literals like this.

Comment: Looks about right to me. The debug console is showing (in breakdown) what will be output to the *real* console. The `@` are some kind of marker/delimiter, the `"` indicate string output and the `\r\n` is what Windows *actually* writes for a newline sent to functions like `printf`.

Comment: Try adding a line like `printf("%d", 42);` to your code and tell/show us how the debug console represents that.